# How can I make multiple files with a loop?

Tags: c

I'm a c language beginner and I'm trying to simulate some physical situation and get some data from it. Right now I can get one data file at once, but I want to improve it by creating several data files at once like

data1.dat
data2.dat
data3.dat
...

But I can't figure out how to create multiple files with different name with a loop.

Is there a specific way to make multiple files with different name?

Comment: make a function to create a file.  Call this function from a loop. And your are done

Comment: Start reading a C text book and/or maybe follow one of the many C tutorials. The question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using `fopen()` to create your files.  `fopen()` takes a string for filename.  You can create the string dynamically in a loop like so:

```
char filename[32];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   sprintf(filename, "data%d.dat", i);
   FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w+");
   // write to file here
   // don't forget to close file when done
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: warning : `FILE * f` rather than `FILE f`

Comment: perhaps it is better if you directly replace "// don't forget to close file when done" by `fclose(fp);` ?

Comment: I used the comment rather than actual `fclose()` because I wanted him to actually think about it rather than just copying the code. But I updated the code to add that and fix the pointer typo.  Thanks.

Comment: I have a question. How does the  `char filename[32];`  work in this code? Can 32 be substituted into other kind of number?

Comment: Just arbitrary number I chose for the maximum length of the file name.  Of course, you need to decide for yourself what the maximum full length would be.